# How to remove - from values in a field- python or pyspark

Tags: python, regex, pyspark, hiveql

I have a field that looks like

```
field1
231-206-2222
231-206-2344
231-206-1111
231-206-1111
```

I tried regexing it but to no avail. I am new to this so any ideas would help. Any suggestions?ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
I tried regexing it but to no avail. I am new to this so any ideas would help. Any suggestions?ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
I tried regexing it but to no avail. I am new to this so any ideas would help. Any suggestions?ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Comment: please show us your regex command. thanks

Comment: Please mention specifically what values you want to remove

Comment: just that dashes in between the number so it is like 2312062344

Comment: `s.replace("-", "")`

Comment: Can you show the code that you tried to no avail?

Comment: in pyspark use [regexp_replace](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a dataframe to me, if so try this:

```
df['field1'].apply(lambda x: x.replace("-",""))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing it.

Demo:

1) # where sub will replace hyphen with empty space

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'field1': ['123-456-999', '333-222-111']})
df['field1'] = df['field1'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'-', '', x))
```

2) # where \D+ will match one or more non-digits and remove it

```
df['field1'] = df['field1'].str.replace(r'\D+', '')
```

3) # to replace - with empty space

```
df['field1'] = df['field1'].str.replace('-', '')
```

Result:

```
    field1
0   123456999
1   333222111
```